# Div gets too wide when 1 column is removed

Tags: layout, html

I'm doing Wordpress theme based on layout that wasn't done by me. The layout originally contains 3 columns, and works fine.

But when i try to remove one column to get 2-columns for content pages, the layout broke, and the #keskimain gets from some reason 2px too wide.

http://tietojohtajakilta.net/wordpress/2-col-test/

What's the reason for this, and is it fixable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick adjustment to following:

```
#keskivas {
   width: 71px;
}

#keskioik {
   width: 62px;
}
```

That lines them everything in up in Firefox. I cannot verify if that will fix your problem in other browsers, however. For future reference, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a very handy tool to help troubleshoot these issues.

EDIT: also setting the following without the above should fix the problem too.

```
#keskimain  {
   width: 970px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it with this. Still not understading why it works like this. 

I got Firebug, but I guess I got the tools but not the skills.. :)